# Axios post unable to read Laravel response

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api, axios

I am building an api authentication with laravel for a React frontend.
The problem is when I do a post with Insomnia to /auth I get the response correctly. But when I do it with axios in React... the response returns null.

**LARAVEL**

```
public function store(AuthRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $this->authService->getCredentials($request->all());

        if (!$token = auth('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->errorResponse("Unauthorized", 401);
        }

        $tokenData = $this->authService->getTokenData($token);

        return response()->json($tokenData);
    }
```

**REACT**

```
export function* signIn({ payload }) {
  const { email, password } = payload;

  const response = yield call(api.post, 'auth', {
    email,
    password,
  });

  console.tron.log(response);

  const { token, user } = response.data;

  yield put(signInSuccess(token, user));

  history.push('home');
}
```

**INSOMNIA**

```
{
  "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9hdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTc2NTg0Nzc1LCJleHAiOjE1NzY1ODgzNzUsIm5iZiI6MTU3NjU4NDc3NSwianRpIjoiSGlnZlNvcVN1OWZaU3AwUyIsInN1YiI6MSwicHJ2IjoiMjNiZDVjODk0OWY2MDBhZGIzOWU3MDFjNDAwODcyZGI3YTU5NzZmNyJ9.SK4c2sm7mVnmZVAqkujYhcPWDHKzmGUjUNzoOsQx7eg",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

**AXIOS**

```
data:""
status:200
statusText:OK
headers:
url:http://localhost:8000/api/auth
method:post
data:{"email":"admin@admin.com","password":"321321"}
baseURL:http://localhost:8000/api
timeout:0
adapter: xhrAdapter()
xsrfCookieName:XSRF-TOKEN
xsrfHeaderName:X-XSRF-TOKEN
maxContentLength:-1
validateStatus: validateStatus()
request:{}
```

Does anyone can help me??

Comment: Is the API and Frontend 2 different projects? Or is the React frontend within the API project?

Comment: two differente projects... one is a react (create-react-app) project and the other is a rest api with laravel

Comment: Looks like the problem is when a send a simple array as response from laravel
example: 
`
["test"=>"ok"]
`
if I send
`
 [
["test"=>"ok"]
]
`
it works